# how to convert time into number in mysql by eliminating :?

Tags: mysql

```
select '1:55:23' as temptime from dual
```

i want to eliminate : value from above query Expected result

```
temptime
 15523
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try:

```
select replace('1:55:23', ':', '') as temptime from dual
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its so simple, i completly forgot this function.